# Causal mediation analysis for time to event endpoints in randomized controlled trial data analysiscausal inference survival-analysis

Tags: mediation, epidemiology

I am struggling with a situation.

I have an RCT where there is an intermediate variable and an ultimate endpoint of survival (a time to event endpoint).

I want to establish that the intermediate variable is a casual mediator of the treatment effect on the ultimate endpoint i.e., OS.

I wonder how can I do that and is there a specific R package that can help me with this? The struggle here is the fact that the confounders only affect the intermediate variable or the mediator and the main endpoint (OS) while the treatment is randomized and not affected by confounders. So even though I tried to use the mediation package, I have been facing difficulty in formulating the two models. In my mind, the outcome model is

```
survreg(Surv(OS,Death)~Treatment*intermediate variable, data = dta)
```

and the mediator model is

```
glm(Intermediate variable~Treatment + C (confounders), data = dta)
```

Are these valid assumptions and good for investigating the causal mediation by the intermediate variable?

Please provide guidance.